# Why is my function returning a strange data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I wrote a function to return how many bird strikes there were for each year. The years and the num of strikes are correct but what's wrong with the first column of my data frame? and why is the last row Strikes NA NA?

```
flightDates <- mdy_hm(birds[,10])
flightYears <- as.factor(year(flightDates))
years <- (c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011))
strikesPerYear <- function(x){
strikes <- c(NA, NA)
for(i in years){  
    countStrikes <- length(which(x == i))
    strikes <- data.frame(rbind(cbind("Year"=i, "NumStrikes"=as.numeric(countStrikes)), strikes))
}
return(strikes)
}

strikesPerYear(flightYears)

> strikesPerYear(flightYears)
        Year NumStrikes
1       2011      10483
110     2010      10923
19      2009      10741
18      2008       8903
17      2007       8746
16      2006       8010
15      2005       7804
14      2004       7667
13      2003       6664
12      2002       6769
11      2001       6287
        2000       6407
strikes   NA         NA
```

Comment: What you call the first column is actually the row.names of the result data.frame and they show the row numbers of the original flightYears data.frame. The last column is `strikes NA NA` because you use `rbind` to row bind it (append) to the strikes data.frame.

Comment: but how do I fix it? I am pulling the dates from a data set and then just keeping the year as "flightYears" I added that info to the questions

Comment: In order to tell you how to fix it, you need to tell us what that means exactly. You haven't precisely described what you want the output to be.

Comment: I get `Error: could not find function "mdy_hm"`, your question is not reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed strikes <- c(NA,NA) to strikes <- data.frame() and that gave me the data frame output I was looking for.

```
flightDates <- mdy_hm(birds[,10])
flightYears <- as.factor(year(flightDates))
years <- (c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011))
strikesPerYear <- function(x){
strikes <- data.frame()
for(i in years){  
countStrikes <- length(which(x == i))
strikes <- data.frame(rbind(cbind("Year"=i, "NumStrikes"=as.numeric    (countStrikes)), strikes))
}
return(strikes)
}

strikesPerYear(flightYears)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first column are `rownames` of the output `data.frame`. It looks like you had a `matrix` as an input (that have `rownames` numbered like: 1,2,3,4,5, ) and somehow you converted `rownames` to characters, or during conversion from `matrix` to `data.frame` they changed they class to characters and your output has `rownames` arranged randomly.

And the last row might be `NA`, `NA` as you have a line in your fnction

```
strikes <- c(NA, NA)
```